# A null pointer exception on a textView in android

Tags: java, android, listview

I am working on an app for school where I have to crate a shopping list and when I select one list I should get a new activity with the products on that list. Now my problem is that when I try to get the clicked element in the listView and then put the products on that list in the listview of the new activity I get a null pointer exception on a textview.

This is the textview that gets the exception

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="#236B8E"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/products_on_list"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the listView in my new activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/shopping_list_details">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here's the java code for the new activity:

```
public class DisplayShoppingListDetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity{


 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //defines the activity layout
        setContentView(R.layout.shopping_list_details);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView_shopping_lists);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String name = intent.getStringExtra("list");

        ProductsOnListAdapter ad = new ProductsOnListAdapter(this, -1, Service.getService().getProductsOnList(name));
        listView.setAdapter(ad);

    }
}
```

this is the fragment where I have the list of shopping lists. Here is where I create the Intent to the new activity:

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
    public Fragment1() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);

        final ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView_shopping_lists);
        // get data from the table by the ListAdapter
        ShoppingListAdapter listAdapter = new ShoppingListAdapter(getActivity(), -1, Service.getService().getShoppingLists());
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {

                // selected item
                // HERE IS THE PROBLEM 
                // I have tried to use rootView instead of view
                TextView textview = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.products_on_list);
                String list = textview.getText().toString();

                // Launching new Activity on selecting single List Item
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DisplayShoppingListDetailsActivity.class);
                // sending data to new activity
                intent.putExtra("list", list);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        //System.out.println("Test: " + Storage.getStorage().getShopingLists());
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

And this is the exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.widget.TextView.getText()' on a null object reference
at com.gnirt69.slidingmenuexample.fragment.Fragment1$1.onItemClick(Fragment1.java:44)
```

the ShoppingListAdapter:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent){

        // Get the data item for this position
        //final ShoppingList list = getItem(position);
        ViewHolder holder;

        // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.items_lists_row, null);

            //set up the viewHolder
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.shoppingListTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        // get the reference to the specific item
        final ShoppingList list = getItem(position);
        //TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        //manipulate the view
        holder.shoppingListTextView.setText(list.getName());

        return convertView;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        private TextView shoppingListTextView;
    }
```

=======EDIT after solving the null pointer=======

Now it opens the new activity but it is empty, it doesn't populate the listview. I am trying yo figure out where exactly I am doing something wrong.

This is my fragment:

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);

        final ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView_shopping_lists);
        // get data from the table by the ListAdapter
        final ShoppingListAdapter listAdapter = new ShoppingListAdapter(getActivity(), -1, Service.getService().getShoppingLists());
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {

                ShoppingList shoppingList = listAdapter.getItem(position);

                // selected item
                TextView textview = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.products_on_list);
                String list = textview.getText().toString();

                // Launching new Activity on selecting single List Item
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DisplayShoppingListDetailsActivity.class);
                // sending data to new activity
                intent.putExtra("list", list);
                //System.out.println(shoppingList.getProductsOnList());
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        //System.out.println("Test: " + Storage.getStorage().getShopingLists());
        return rootView;
    }
```

The new activity that should display the products on the clicked list but it doesn't:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //defines the activity layout
        setContentView(R.layout.shopping_list_details);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.shopping_list_details);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String name = intent.getStringExtra("list");

        ProductsOnListAdapter ad = new ProductsOnListAdapter(this, -1, Service.getService().getProductsOnList(name));
        listView.setAdapter(ad);

    }
```

And the adapter:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent){

        // Get the data item for this position
        //final ShoppingList list = getItem(position);
        ViewHolder holder;

        // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.shopping_list_details, null);

            //set up the viewHolder
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.productsTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.products_on_list);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        // get the reference to the specific item
        final ProductOnList product = getItem(position);
        //TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        //manipulate the view
        holder.productsTextView.setText(product.toString());

        return convertView;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        private TextView productsTextView;
    }
```

Comment: Can you please upload the `ShoppingListAdapter` class?

Comment: I have added it at the end of the post

Comment: You should be able to do something like `ShoppingList list = listAdapter .getItem(position)` in order to get the list at the clicked position.

Comment: okay and then how do I send the data to the new activity because if I do: intent.putExtra("list", shoppingList); it gives me an error.

Answer (score 0):

I think the Problem is that you want to call a Textview from layout

```
setContentView(R.layout.shopping_list_details);
```

But your fragment uses the layout

```
final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);
```

You can work around this issue by passing the TextView to your Fragment from the Main or change your xml Layout

You can test if this is true by adding a textview with the same id to the fragment1 layout.

Comment: I have added a textview with the same id to fragment1 and it runs now but it doesn't fetch the data, the view is blank

Comment: Where do you start your Fragment? Does the AppCompatActivity see it? @AuroraBrignola

Comment: I don't think the fragment has anything to do with this, but I am probably wrong. I start it in the main activity.

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to the same ListView `R.id.listView_shopping_lists` in your new Activity and your Fragment, you never target `shopping_list_details` in your Activity layout file which will contain each item, therefore the TextView is null.

Comment: true story, I've fixed this and now it doesn't run into any error and it opens the new activity but blank, with no data in the listview

Comment: If the Activity launches with no data displayed I would say you have narrowed down the problem to the Activity & Adapter. I would use log print outs or breakpoints to see what data (if any) is being returned by your Service, and then check that it's being set correctly within the adapter.

Comment: @AuroraBrignola If you have fixed something with the code in the question, can you please make a new edit to your post explaining the new problem?

Comment: @cricket_007 done...I have tested with a print out my service and everything is fine in there, the items are printed correctly.

Comment: I think the problem is in my fragment, where I pass the shopping list to the intent but when I try to do this:  intent.putExtra("ShoppingList", shoppingList); it gives a casting error.

Comment: and then when I make my ShoppingList class Serializable I get  type incompatibility... kill me now :(((((

Comment: fixed that too...now I am back to the same null pointer exception I've started with >:(  "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference" in my Adapter

Comment: FIXED ALL ISSUES. It is now finally working :D THANKS A LOOOOT FOR THE HELP :3